# Handling missed keys for Struts Message Resource file

Tags: jsp, internationalization, struts, jsp-tags

I have to handle the case when `JspException: Missing message for key ...` occurs. I'm getting various key-definitions, these what i have defined to translate i want to translate, when definition don't exist in i18n file i want to leave it unchanged.

My JSP code looks like:

```
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
...

<% String propertyname_i18n_key = "mypage.section1." + property.getPropName();%>
<bean:define id="propName_i18n"><bean:message key='<%=propertyname_i18n_key%>'/></bean:define>
<% if(propName_i18n != null){
    out.println(propName_i18n);
}else{
    out.println(property.getPropName()); }%>
```

So when my i18n def looks like:

```
mypage.section1.name=Name
mypage.section1.url=URL
mypage.section1.encoding-error=Encoding error
```

I want to get:

```
name -> Name
url -> URL
trandlate-error -> translate-error
encoding-error -> Encoding error
something-not-defined -> something-not-defined
```

instead of `JspException: Missing message for key 'mypage.section1.translate-error'`.

Comment: I don't see properties key `mypage.section1.translate-error` in your example. Are you sure you have it declared in your properties file?